# ERROR: Convert and Save Base64 String into a File

Tags: c#, imap

*Edited

Pardon me as I may not have been clear on this one. The code throwing the error is:

```
Convert.FromBase64String(base64)
```

Is there ***another way*** to convert the base64 string into bytes in C# other than the method above?

---

I need help with file conversions using ***C#***. I am trying to *convert* a ***base64*** string into a file and *save* it into my desktop. The file to be saved is either a ***text***, ***excel*** or ***pdf*** file. The code I used was this:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\{thefilename}", Convert.FromBase64String(base64));
```

However, I am getting an error:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
>   among the padding characters

I tried to **save the base64 into a text file first** then used https://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html to convert it to check if the base64 was really in the correct format. When I did that, it converted the ***base64 into its original file***.

May I ask how I am able to resolve this error? Is this error caused by limitations from C# or is it because of the base64 that I had? I don't think it's the latter since I was able to convert it online into its actual file. Is there perhaps any other way to convert a base64 into a file in C# apart from the method I used above?

Comment: From where you are getting `base64`?, is it possible can you post your base64 string here?

Comment: @programtreasures I am using the IMAP FETCH functionality to retrieve an email attachment. A sample command is this _imapSw.WriteLine("a05 FETCH " + Index + " BODY[2]"); 

This returns a base64 string. 

Unfortunately, I am unable to post the base64 string here because of two reasons: first is because it contains sensitive data; second is because it is a fairly big sting, more than 1 mb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found the answer to my error. I was able to resolve the error by opening the text file that I saved my base64 string into and then updating it by removing the padding and re-adding it again. The steps went like this:

1. Save base64 string into text file
2. Open text file
3. Remove padding
4. Save file.
5. Re-add removed padding
6. Save file.
7. Get base64 string from twice-updated text file
8. Call method `Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);`

I'm not sure what caused this issue in the first place. Does anyone know why this is happening? Or is this a Windows OS issue, C# issue or both?

Comment: its strange, can you please post here with dummy string?

Comment: I haven't actually solved it through code yet s it. But what I did was to first call the method File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\{thefilename}", Convert.FromBase64String(base64));. After that, I manually open the text file, and click CTRL + S. Then I read the file through code using base64= File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\{thefilename}); And lastly convert it into a file using File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\file.xlsx", Convert.FromBase64String(base64));

Comment: when you first call `File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\{thefilename}", Convert.FromBase64String(base64));` is it succeed?

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake there. The first File.WriteAllBytes is supposed to be File.WriteAllText.

Answer (score 1):

I suspected that your `Base64String` has prefix like `data:image/pdf;base64`. So, you should remove it before converting to byte array.

```
base64 = base64.Replace("data:image/pdf;base64,","");
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\{thefilename}", Convert.FromBase64String(base64));
```

Comment: Is that prefix appended to the base64 string? I checked the base64 and it did not contain the string mentioned above. It also did not contain any english words.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pad "=" to the right of the string if the length of base64 string is not a multiple of 4. i,e.

If Base64 string is 7 character long then we add 1 "="s

If Base64 string is 6 character long then we add 2 "="s

If Base64 string is 5 character long then we the string is corrupted already. So there cannot be a case when the base64 string length be 1, 5, 11, 16 etc.

Comment: I have a code that checks if the base64 length is valid. int value = base64.Length%4; I have also made sure that the base64 has a padding (==) at the end. Do you know of any other way to convert a base64 string into a byte array using C#?

Comment: Padding should be = or == based on length not always ==

Answer (score 0):

I tried to convert `base64` string to file to `jpg` and `pdf` before. I think it should work for other file extention too. Try this.

```
var imgByte = Convert.FromBase64String("base64");
var path = "..../file.jpg";

try{

     var _FStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
     _FStream.GetAccessControl();
     _FStream.Write(imgByte, 0, imgByte.Length);
     _FStream.Close();
     _FStream.Dispose();

} catch (Exception ex){
     var errorMsg = ex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the method throwing the error is the Convert.FromBase64String();. According to the error, it cannot execute the method because the base64 string supplied is valid. Is there another function/method that converts a base64 string into a byte?

Comment: @thecodeexplorer I use the same website as you to convert and try. Is your `base64` string valid? Or you try a simple image string to try first?

Comment: I have a checking that checks the length of the base64 string if it is valid. I also have a condition that checks if the base64 contains a padding at the end (""). Apart from the checks I have done, is there a specific checking that I have to do to test if my base64 is valid?

Comment: Maybe add `try catch` when converting. And also debug, get that string and paste it back to the website to see whether it convert back the actual one.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe a variant or obsolete encoding or any number of things

You should probably read the the   [Base64 Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

> Implementations may have some constraints on the alphabet used for
>   representing some bit patterns. This notably concerns the last two
>   characters used in the index table for index 62 and 63, and the
>   character used for padding (which may be mandatory in some protocols,
>   or removed in others)

There are several implementations and RFCs, take note of the **Variants summary table**

Since you cant give us the input we have no idea what variant it is

If the input is the right length then it might be just as easy to replace the variant characters, once again its impossible to know because cant see the input

```
string corrected = input.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
var decodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(corrected);
```